# How to add more AR markers to ar_sys?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering if anyone knows how to add more AR makers and boards in ar_sys: http://wiki.ros.org/ar_sys

Is this possible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220472/how-to-add-more-ar-markers-to-ar_sys?/) by [K7](https://answers.ros.org/users/23630/k7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2015-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try [this online generator](http://terpconnect.umd.edu/%7Ejwelsh12/enes100/markergen.html) for markers!
As for boards, I am afraid you need to independently compile Aruco examples.

---

Originally posted by [sahloul](https://answers.ros.org/users/20184/sahloul/) with karma: 18 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0